# Nginx: Rewrite file extension

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

How can i rewrite a .swf file extension?? This is my syntax which does not work:

rewrite ^/directory/swift$ directory/tools/swift_file.swf last;

Answer (score 0):

You missed leading `/` in replacement.

Also, for single file instead of rewriting you can use `alias`:

```
location = /directory/swift {
    alias /directory/tools/swift_file.swf;
}
```